# "Oder" im Titel eines Buches

Tags: usage

Ich sehe ab und zu Buchtitel o.Ä., wie z.B. von den Grimms: *Der Froschkönig oder der eiserne Heinrich*, die durch ein "oder" in zwei Titel unterteilt werden. Ich weiß nicht, ob es nur in dem deutschen Sprachraum so gewöhnlich ist/war, aber ich würde mich freuen über eine Erklärung zu dieser Gewohnheit. Warum soll bzw. will man zwei Namen für sein Buch nennen? Was it der Ursprung dieser Praktik?

Comment: Ich bezweifle, dass das eine Eigenart des Deutschen ist. Der Titel von "Dr. Seltsam oder wie ich lernte, die Bombe zu lieben" lautet im Englischen "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb". Dafür die Verfilmung des deutschen Kinderbuchs "Konrad oder das Kind aus der Konservendose" auf Englisch "Konrad or the Child out of the Tin". Scheint also im Englischen genauso verbreitet zu sein.

Comment: "Der Hobbit" heißt im Original "The Hobbit or There and Back Again", "Frankenstein" ist "Frankenstein, or the Modern Prometheus."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a allegedly German phenomenon which is in fact international.

Comment: I think, this question could stay open. Although it is not a phenomenon limited to German, it is still a phenomenon in German literature. That something is not an exclusively German phenomenon, holds true for many things in German literature. Even in a comparative perspective, the question is valid, how this phenomenon came into German literature. Was it imported from different literatures? Was it invented in Germany and later distributed to other literatures? In my humble opinion, there is enough aspects about German to keep this question in scope of german.SE.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, den Testbaustein [sic!] gibt das System beim Markieren als *off topic* automatisch aus.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich denke, da bist du auf der falschen Spur - Nach deiner Argumentation könnte man auch fragen "warum reimen sich deutsche Gedichte?"

Comment: Eine Spekulation: Volkstümliche Geschichten können unter unterschiedlichen Titeln kursiert sein, so dass man beiden Kulturkreisen bedeutet, dass sie hier richtig sind. Zweite Spekulation: Man kann sich nicht für einen der Titel entscheiden bzw. möchte die Information beider Titel mitgeben. Dritte: Cargocult. Man hat es bei anderen gesehen und glaubt, es wäre sinnvoll, man müsse das auch machen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Das System gibt den Textbaustein nicht automatisch *aus* sondern es gibt ihn *vor.* Das ist nur ein Textbaustein, nichts weiter. Den darf man markieren, löschen und durch eine deutsche Übersetzung ersetzen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Man darf ihn aber auch nehmen, wie er ist und mit einem englischen Text ausrüsten - Nein, das ist kein Verbrechen. ;) Die blaue "closed"-Box kommt dann sowieso in Englisch

Comment: @tofro Kann man das denn nicht fragen?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Doch, kann man fragen. Wäre aber (zumindestens meiner Meinung nach) off-topic ;)

Comment: @tofro Ja :) Deine reductio ad absurdum scheitert bei mir daran, dass ich dein absurdum nicht absurd finde. Um mich zu überzeugen, bräuchtest du ein anderes Argument. Aber lass uns das lieber im Chat klären.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Eine topic-Diskussion gehört nicht in den Chat - Wenn schon, dann solte das auf Meta diskutiert werden. Ich hab' nur grade keine Zeit, da eine Frage aufzumachen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Darf man, muss man aber nicht. Schließlich sollte das System das auf Deutsch anbieten. Das könnten diejenigen, denen die englische Sprache ab und zu stört, in der Meta fragen.